# Как изменять iframe

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe

Здравствуйте. Нужна помощь. Как изменять содержимое `iframe` с помощью `jquery` чтоб содержимое менялось и в самом `iframe` и на самой странице которую мы вставляем в `iframe`.

[Пример](http://evrikagames.magegu.ru/)

`логин - kasimov`
`пароль - 12345`

Выберите квест и посмотрите на игровой экран. Как это сделать?

Comment: никак (совсем никак)

Answer (score 2):

Здесь возможны 2 варианта:

1. Этот `iframe` "свой" (т.е. отображает страницу **с того же** домена или сервера).
   Тогда Вам возможно поможет [это решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439303/detect-click-event-inside-iframe).
2. Этот `iframe` "чужой" (т.е. отображает страницу **с другого** домена или сервера).
   Тогда изменить его содержимое не возможно. Это сделано разработчиками специально из соображений безопасности.

Comment: Данный способ помогает визуально изменить его
Если нажать посмотреть в отдельном окне то все пропадает
Сохраняется только на странице где вставлен этот iframe
А мне желательно бы чтоб оно сохранялось хотя бы до перезагрузки страницы

Comment: Это естественно. При вызове просмотра в отдельном окне страница генерируется с нуля. Это уже другой экземпляр страницы, который ничего не знает ни об `iframe`, ни, тем более, о Ваших манипуляциях с ним. Но, с другой стороны, если `iframe` у Вас "свой", то, что мешает добавить соответствующую обработку на стороне сервера?

Comment: iframe свой можно поподробней какую обработку я должен сделать я просто не могу понять принцип
Вот посмотрите пожалуйста на том сайте как сделано у него меняется и в этом iframe который на начальной странице и после нажатия кнопки "открыть в доп окне" то и там это сохраняется
Вот мне нужно так же сделать